# Laravel -- Route Name Replaced with Full URI?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working on a developer tool (closed source at the moment, unfortunately) that reports on Laravel route names.  It does so with code that works *mostly* like this (this is simplified to make asking this question easier).

```
function identifyRoute() {
    $router = app('router');
    $route  = $router->current();

    $name   = $route->name;
    if($name) {
        return $name;
    }

    $action = $route->getAction();
    if(isset($action["controller"]) && $action["controller"]) {
        return $action["controller"];
    }

    if($name = $route->uri())
    {
        return $name;
    }

    return 'Could Not Identify Name';
}
```

So, for a route like

```
Route::get('foo/{id}/bar', function($id ) {
    //...      
});
```

Our function returns the string `foo/{id}/bar`.  Or, it *usually* returns the string `foo/{id}/bar`.  We've had reports from users that sometimes this method of identifying routes returns results like

```
foo/1234/bar
foo/1235/bar
foo/1236/bar
foo/1237/bar
```

That is, it's returning the entire URI for the request.

Is there some Laravel setting (or popular extension/plugin) that could replace the results of calls to `getName`, `uri`, or the controller name, with the full URI of the request?

Comment: Which version are the users, that report the error, running?

Comment: @Ice76 The ones we know about are on 5.4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but an `OPTIONS` HTTP request will return a 200 response with the proper allowable verbs, using the requested path as-is instead of a pattern.

[Current source code in 5.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.7.24/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L225-L243)

[Method is almost the same in 5.4.9](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.4.9/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L203-L221)

Comment: Good guess, this was it.  Thank you! (also, trying hard not to grumble about Laravel not handling this with middleware)